# perl simple grep

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I want to create a simple grep call in perl.
I have 2 variables.
$var1,$var2
and I want to get all the files that the name of the file starts with $var1 and the end of the file is $var2
what would be the syntax for a grep command in perl that does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gets all file names in the current directory that start with `$var1` and end with `$var2`:

```
my @matchingFileNames = <$var1*$var2>;
```

EDIT: To handle spaces and special characters as @Schwern and @ikegami correctly pointed out:

```
my @matchingFileNames = <\Q$var1\E*\Q$var2\E>;
```

Comment: If `$var1` or `$var2` contain `*` or `'` or something it will be interpreted by the shell giving the wrong result.  $var1 and $var2 must be quoted first with `quotemeta`.

Comment: Or if they contains a space (much more common)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
my @files = grep {/\A$var.*$var2\z/} @input_files
```

will do

Comment: or you could break it up which will make it slightly easier to read (and faster): `my @files = grep {/\A$var1/ && /$var2\z/} @input_files;`

Comment: Use //i modifier, and also \Q...\E, file names will probably have dots (.) or some other regex meta characthers.

Answer (score 0):

```
opendir(DIR, "yourDIR");
my @FILES= readdir(DIR);
my @matching_files;

for my $file (@FILES) {
  push(@matching_files, $file) if ($file =~ /\A$var1/ and $file =~ /$var2\z/)
}
```

Comment: That for loop is the longer, slower way to write `my @matching_files = grep { m{\A$var1} and m{$var2\z} } @files`.